# AS3: Create motion-tween through ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've created a simple shape(MovieClip) in main Scene.

So, i wanna move that shape via `Motion Tween` in ActionScript.

Please tell me how can i do that ?

**Notice :**

I'm not talking about create `Motion Tween` in flash timeline. I need to do that in ActionScript.

P.S :

I'm using Flash Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example code from [official reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html).

```
 import fl.transitions.Tween;
 import fl.transitions.easing.*;
 var myTween:Tween = new Tween(myObject, "x", Elastic.easeOut, 0, 300, 3, true);
```

Also here is a [tutorial](http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-tweening-with-actionscript-30--active-2022) to the topic.

Just for your info: you can tween not only position of the object but also other numeric parameters, e.g. width and height.

Answer (score 3):

As much as Tween class can help you, I strongly encourage you not to use it. Mainly for the performance reason.

To tween effectively, easy and fast I recommend you to use a free open-source tweener called TweenLite: http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

It is a very advanced tool, there are many examples and tutorials on how to use it, but it can all come down to a small line like this one:

```
TweenLite.to(yourObject, duration, {x: EndX, y: EndY});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move your object on the X and Y axes, you will need two tweens. Here is the code in ActionScript 3:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

var tweenX:Tween = new Tween(nameOfYourObject, "x", Strong.easeIn, startPositionX, endPositionX, numberOfSeconds, true);
var tweenY:Tween = new Tween(nameOfYourObject, "y", Strong.easeIn, startPositionY, endPositionY, numberOfSeconds, true);
```

Make sure to define the starting and ending positions for both x and y and the number of seconds you want the tween to last.